# Web Mining Represent My Website

Tags: algorithm, data-mining

In my website there are a lot of pages and documents, some of pages have a link to another pages.

What's the best way to represent the whole website in data mining or web mining? and what's the best technique to do that? and should I use web content mining or web usage mining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first you may know what's exactly the web mining working on:

**Web data is:**

- Web content – text, image, records, etc.
- Web structure – hyperlinks, tags, etc.
- Web usage – http logs, app server logs, etc.

**For Web Content:**

Extract “snippets” from a Web document that represents the Web Document.

That's mean that the Web Content Mining is the process of extracting useful information from the contents of Web documents you may need here to use (Information Retrieval (IR) and natural language
processing (NLP))

But first you need some preprocessing stages for the content like:

- Extract text from HTML.
- Remove Stop Words.
- Calculate Collection Wide Word Frequencies (DF).
- Calculate per Document Term Frequencies (TF).

And the Common Mining Techniques for web content are (classification, clustering and Associations).

**For Web Structure:**

Identifying interesting graph patterns or preprocessing the whole web graph to come up with metrics such as PageRank.

So the web structure mining is that the structure of a typical Web graph consists of Web pages as nodes, and hyperlinks as edges connecting between two related pages, and is the process of discovering structure information from the Web, and I think here is your scope for you problem.

What's the terminology you can use here in your case it's Graph (direct graph) where:

- Web-graph: A directed graph that represents the Web.
- Node: Each Web page is a node of the Web-graph.
- Link: Each hyperlink on the Web is a directed edge of the Web-graph.
- In-degree: The in-degree of a node, p, is the number of distinct links that point to p.
- Out-degree : The out-degree of a node, p, is the number of distinct links originating at other nodes.
- Directed Path: A sequence of links, starting from p that can be followed to reach q.

[image]

**For Web Usage:**

User identification, session creation, robot detection and filtering, and extracting usage path patterns